# can't find all field of a pdf (acroform)

Tags: pdfbox

Considering [this pdf](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Xweu4UZWRc9BIVd5hkgMoCafhTlaHGnl&export=download)

With this code  I except retrieve all field but I get half of them:

```
pdfOriginal.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields().forEach(field -> {
  System.out.println(field.getValueAsString());
});
```

What is wrong here ? It seems all annotations are not in aocroform reference, what is the correct way to add form field annotation into acroform object?

#### Update 1

The wierd thing here if I tried to set field's value which is not referenced/found in `getAcroForm.getFields()` like this :

```
doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("fieldNotInGetFields").setValue("a");
```

This works

#### Update 2

It seems using `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFieldTree()` retrieve all fields. I don't understand why `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields()` not ?

What is the correct way retrieve all fields of a pdf `acroform.getFieldTree()` or `acroform.getFields()` (I need retrieve them to set them partialValue)

Comment: Please read the javadoc of the two, it explains this.

Comment: already did that, was out of scope to me, but after few code-try it is clear to me now ! thank you a lot @TilmanHausherr, let me answer to my question with little code example or you prefer delete it ?

Comment: Please answer yourself :-)

Comment: If there is anything that you think should be added to the javadoc, please mention it.

Comment: javadoc seems clear can't do better here ^^ was my fault

Answer (score 1):

From the java doc on method `public List<PDField> getFields()` we can read:

> A field might have children that are fields (non-terminal field) or does not have children which are fields (terminal fields).

In my case some fields contain **non-terminal field** so to print them all we need check if we are in a `PDNonTerminalField` like :

```
document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields().forEach(f -> {
    listFields(f);              
});

// loop over PDNonTerminalField otherwise print field value
public static void listFields(PDField f){
    if(f instanceof PDNonTerminalField) {
        ((PDNonTerminalField) f).getChildren().forEach(ntf-> {
            listFields(ntf);
        });         
    }else {
        System.out.println(f.getValueAsString());
    }
}
```